# PHP dynamic multidimensional Array

Tags: php

I have a problem with the implementation of a dynamic 2 dimensional array. This is the way I am doing this:

```
$array_ = array();
$values = array();

foreach ($queryresult as $row){
    array_push($value, $row['id'];
    array_push($value, $row['title'];
    array_push($array_, $value);
}  
var_dump(#array_);
```

The problem is that my query returns 3 rows, but my result is as follows:-

```
Array ([0] => Array ([0] => 44 [1] => Game of Thrones))
```

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `$array_ = new Array();` that's not valid PHP syntax. Remove "new", arrays are not objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$array_ = Array();

foreach ($queryresult as $row){
    $values = Array();

    array_push($values, $row['id'];
    array_push($values, $row['title'];
    array_push($array_, $values);
}  
var_dump($array_);
```

or even simpler

```
$array_ = Array();

foreach ($queryresult as $row){
    array_push($array_, 
        array(
            $row['id'],
            $row['title']
        )
    );
}  
var_dump($array_);
```

Answer (score 2):

Much cleaner.

```
$array_ = [];

foreach ($queryresult as $row){
   $array_[] = [$row['id'], $row['title']];
}  

var_dump($array_);
```